# SQLite Greatest-N-Per-Group for sanitising imported data

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have a task to write SQL to sanitise and de-duplicate an imported data-set.

```
 pk1 | pk2 | timestamp | value1 | value2 | value3 | etc
-----+-----+-----------+--------+--------+--------+----- 

  1  |  2  |    123    |   1    |   2    |   5    |  ...
  1  |  2  |    124    |   1    |   2    |   4    |  ...
  1  |  2  |    125    |   1    |   2    |   3    |  ...   Either this row
  1  |  2  |    125    |   1    |   2    |   2    |  ...   Or this row (arbitrary)

  3  |  2  |    123    |   1    |   2    |   5    |  ...
  3  |  2  |    123    |   1    |   2    |   4    |  ...
  3  |  2  |    124    |   1    |   2    |   3    |  ...
  3  |  2  |    125    |   1    |   2    |   2    |  ...   Only this row
```

The two `pk` fields are the composite primary key.

The `timestamp` field identifies when the data was generated.

I need one row per `pk1, pk2`, with highest `timestamp` taking priority.  There can still be duplicates (`1, 2, 125` appears twice in the set above), at which point an arbitrary row should be selected and a field set so signify that this was an arbitrary selection.

I have answers for MySQL and RDBMS that support ANALYTICAL_FUNCTIONS()...

**MySQL :**

```
SELECT
  import.*,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END   AS AS duplicate_warning
FROM
  import
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT pk1, pk2, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM import
GROUP BY pk1, pk2
)
  AS import_lookup
    ON  import_lookup.pk1       = import_lookup.pk1
    AND import_lookup.pk2       = import_lookup.pk2
    AND import_lookup.timestamp = import_lookup.timestamp
GROUP BY
  import.pk1,
  import.pk2
```

**ANALYTICAL_FUNCTIONS() :**

```
SELECT
  sorted_import.*
FROM
(
  SELECT
    import.*,
    CASE WHEN
      COUNT(*)       OVER (PARTITION BY pk1, pk2, timestamp) = 1
      AND
      MAX(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY pk1, pk2)            = timestamp
    THEN
      0
    ELSE
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pk1, pk2 ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
    END  AS duplicate_warning
  FROM
    import
)
  AS sorted_import
WHERE
  sorted_import.duplicate_warning IN (0, 1)
```

How can this be accomplished using SQLite?

One restriction *(I don't make these rules)* : Can't use temp tables or auto-increment fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, the values of non-aggregated columns are guaranteed to come from a row that matches a single MIN or MAX:

```
SELECT *, MAX(timestamp)
FROM import
GROUP BY pk1, pk2
```

Comment: Hmm, that should mean that the MySQL example is compatible with SQLite.  I'll check the version, thanks for confirming this.

Comment: Does MySQL guarantee this, or does it just take the values from the last row in the group?

Comment: Not sure, will investigate, but in my example above I use a sub-query to isolate the max-timestamp.  I just need to *then* pick an arbitrary row from that group.  Your description for SQLite suggests that SQLite doesn't need the sub-query, but having that sub-query there does cover my arse in the case of arbitrary MySQL behaviour ;)

Comment: I'll also have to investigate what happens in SQLite for `SELECT table.*, MIN(x), MAX(x) FROM table GROUP BY table.pk`...